# Producing a thin version of Computer Modern by tweaking the Metafont parameters

Tags: metafont, computer-modern

I am hoping to produce a custom version of all Computer Modern glyphs, where the parameters are tweaked such that the pen strokes are very thin (essentially no filling, just central skeleton strokes).
My objective is to use `autotrace` to convert those strokes to SVG paths, resulting in single-stroke glyphs for use in other programs (pen-plotters, Mathjax, etc.)

The Metafont and CM books are a bit overwhelming, so I would appreciate advice / simple examples to point me in the right direction, specifically:

1. How would one go about producing all of CM's glyphs, with a current TeX distribution?
2. What's the best place to find all the parameters that will need to be tuned to make thin, constant-width strokes?

*Edit:* to clarify, here's a depiction of what I'm after

Starting from the Metafont sources (here [copied from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metafont))

```
%file name: beta.mf
%mode_setup;
% Define a beanlike shape for the character B
beginchar("B",11pt#,11pt#,0);
  % Setup coordinates as an equation system
  y1=y2=y3=0;
  y4=y5=y6=h;
  x1=x4=0;
  x2=x5=w;
  x3=x6=2*w;

  % Define pen
  pickup pencircle xscaled 0.2w yscaled 0.04w rotated 45;

  % Draw the character curve
  % z1 is the same as (x1, y1)
  draw z1..z3..z6{z2-z6}..z5..{z4-z2}z4..cycle;
endchar;

end
```

one can produce a glyph (raster or vector, it's not important), which is then processed by autotrace (e.g. via Inkscape) to get just the central line,

[image: screenshot of the autotrace]

Now, I wish to do this programmatically for over 2200 glyphs from Computer Modern, and many have strokes that will confuse the algorithm because they vary too much in thickness. I would like to help the autotrace algorithm by first producing a version of CM glyphs that have nearly uniform strokes.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Have you checked out [`cmathbb`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/cmathbb/doc/cmathbb.pdf)?

Comment: The original METAFONT sources are designed to produce bitmap, not outline fonts. For a new variant of Computer Modern, you might want to edit an OpenType clone in a program such as FontForge.

Comment: @Davislor I've edited the question, hopefully it's clearer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  Metafont sources for CM fonts are in `fonts/source/public/cm/` in TeXlive. Each file with real font name (for example `cmr10.mf`) includes setting about 60 parameters and the last line is `generate roman` or `generate textit` etc. This runs the files where all characters are described by procedures, these procedures use the mentioned parameters as global variables. So, if you change a parameter in `cmr10.mf` then all characters are changed.

You can run `mf '\mode=supre; mode_setup; input cmr10.mf'` to generate `cmr10.2400gf` file with bitmaps of all characters in 2400 dpi resolution. You can apply `gftopk cmr10.2400gf` to create compressed format of the mf output in the file `cmr10.2400pk`. The high resolution is desired for the next autotracing process.

If you whish to generate all CM glyphs by single command, try

```
for i in cm*.mf ; do mf '\mode=supre; mode_setup; input' $i; done
```

**Edit** If you want to create `png` files (one character per one file), then you can use `dvipng` software. First, create your version of bitmap from `cmr10.2400pk` to `cmr10.2400pk` using `gftopk` and leave it in your actual directory. Then you can create a file (say `cm.tex`):

```
\font\f=cmr10 scaled 6000
\f
\nopagenumbers

a
\vfil\break 
b
\vfil\break % ... etc

\bye
```

Run `tex cm` to create `cm.dvi`. Each letter is at single page. Finally run `dvipng --freetype0 cm`. It creates a bunch of `cm*.png` files. Because the default resolution of `dvipng` is 400, we scale fonts 6times (see `\font` command) to get the resolution 2400 in our result. When the `--freetype0` option is used, then `dvipg` uses bitmap fonts, it searches fonts in 6x400=2400 resolution and uses the file `cmr10.2400pk` prepared by you.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I wonder if there's an easy "pk to png" kind of utility that outputs individual glyphs as png files?

Comment: Also wondering if it's easy to locate the parameters that would influence the pen width / width variation (I guess it'll best described in the Metafont / CM book?)

Comment: I added information about `dvipng`.

Comment: Thanks – I found another thread on making CM **bolder**, so that should be similar